# Problem with pdf invoices in woocommerce pdf invoices and packing slips

Tags: woocommerce, invoice

I have a problem with pdf invoices in woocommerce pdf invoices and packing slips. Because if customer change goods and he want to send an invoice to email he receives not full invoice but packing slip (but in preview it's looking good, like an invoice). And I also have an error in woocommerce logs
INFO Lock (updraft_lock_wpo_wcpdf_invoice_number_lock, wp_options) acquired
INFO Lock option (updraft_lock_wpo_wcpdf_invoice_number_lock, wp_options) released
INFO Lock (updraft_lock_wpo_wcpdf_invoice_number_lock, wp_options) acquired
INFO Lock option (updraft_lock_wpo_wcpdf_invoice_number_lock, wp_options) released
INFO Lock (updraft_lock_wpo_wcpdf_invoice_number_lock, wp_options) acquired
INFO Lock option (updraft_lock_wpo_wcpdf_invoice_number_lock, wp_options) released

I've already checked all tools and settings in  woocommerce pdf invoices and packing slips, there everything ok with settings. And now I don't know what I can do next